# Find origin of language warnings and errors in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code will sometimes give you warnings or errors for your code, usually indicated by:

- as "Problems" in the respective pane (the "Focus on Problems View")
- yellow or red squiggly lines under the offending code
- in tooltips when hovering the offending code
- inline when you click "View Problem" or use ALT+F8

[image: screenshot of the above four options]

None of these UI features seem to tell me: **how to find *the origin* of such warnings and errors?** Which extension or rule or linter or built-in feature is responsible for that specific problem?

Often the warnings and errors make sense, or you can *deduce* what must be the originator. But sometimes this is not so obvious, and to find the right documentation for said error (to get more information on the reason, rationale, potential fixes, etc.) I'd need to know what *caused* the warning or error.

For example the "*Unkown rule*" error from my screenshot *presumably* comes from [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint) since they have [a specific rule around that](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/at-rule-no-unknown/README.md). I want to know how I can find this out *from within VSCode*?

My current workarounds include "*fiddling around until the error disappears*", and "*Googling error messages to inevitably find a Stack Overflow post that explains things*", but I want to *understand* what's going on, and what the root of the errors is.

Comment: What exactly do you want to find? I understand wanting to know the extension name, but how do you expect to get *"reason, rationale, potential fixes"*?

Comment: I'll clarify the question in a sec. At the very least I want to know what "thing" was responsible so I can check their documentation. Even better if there turns out to be "More info" somehow.